# Downloading images from rets feed using phprets

Tags: php, rets

I am trying to use PHPRETS to download RETS FEED Data and Images, I am successful in downloading data as CSV but, though images are created in the image folder properly, the size of each image is zero. I am attaching the code I am using here, please help me so that I can download images properly.

```
    <?php

    $rets_login_url = "http://retsgw.flexmls.com:80/rets2_0/Login";
    $rets_username = "**********";
    $rets_password = "**********";

   // use http://retsmd.com to help determine the SystemName of the DateTime field which
   // designates when a record was last modified
   $rets_modtimestamp_field = "LIST_87";

   // use http://retsmd.com to help determine the names of the classes you want to pull.
   // these might be something like RE_1, RES, RESI, 1, etc.
   $property_classes = array("B");

   // DateTime which is used to determine how far back to retrieve records.
   // using a really old date so we can get everything
    $previous_start_time = "1980-01-01T00:00:00";     require_once("lib/phrets.php");

   // start rets connection
   $rets = new phRETS;

   // only enable this if you know the server supports the optional RETS feature called 'Offset'
    $rets->SetParam("offset_support", true);

    echo "+ Connecting to {$rets_login_url} as {$rets_username}<br>\n";
    $connect = $rets->Connect($rets_login_url, $rets_username, $rets_password);

    if ($connect) {
    echo "  + Connected<br>\n";
    }
    else {
      echo "  + Not connected:<br>\n";
    print_r($rets->Error());
    exit;
    }

    foreach ($property_classes as $class) {

    echo "+ Property:{$class}<br>\n";

    $file_name = strtolower("property_{$class}.csv");
    $fh = fopen($file_name, "w+") or die("Can't open file");

    $fields_order = array();

    $query = "({$rets_modtimestamp_field}={$previous_start_time}+)";

    // run RETS search
    echo "   + Resource: Property   Class: {$class}   Query: {$query}<br>\n";
    $search = $rets->SearchQuery("Property", $class, $query, array('Limit' => 1000));
    $get_id = $_REQUEST['LIST_1'];
    if ($rets->NumRows($search) > 0) {

            // print filename headers as first line
            $fields_order = $rets->SearchGetFields($search);
            fputcsv($fh, $fields_order);

            // process results
            while ($record = $rets->FetchRow($search)) {
                    $this_record = array();
                    foreach ($fields_order as $fo)  {

    if ($fo == 'LIST_1') {

        $photos = $rets->GetObject("Property", "Photo", $record[$fo], "*", 1);

        foreach ($photos as $photo) {

            if ($photo['Success'] == true) {

                 file_put_contents("photos/{$photo['Content-ID']}-{$photo['Object-ID']}.jpg", $photo['Data']);   

            }   
        }
    }
  $this_record[] = $record[$fo];
}                           
    fputcsv($fh, $this_record);    
            }

    }

    echo "    + Total found: {$rets->TotalRecordsFound($search)}<br>\n";

    $rets->FreeResult($search);

    fclose($fh);

    echo "  - done<br>\n";

    }

    echo "+ Disconnecting<br>\n";
    $rets->Disconnect();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have this line. It is returning the image URL, not the binary image data.

```
$photos = $rets->GetObject("Property", "Photo", $record[$fo], "*", 1);
```

The fifth argument should be a 0.

```
$photos = $rets->GetObject("Property", "Photo", $record[$fo], "*", 0);
```

According to the PHRETS documentation, a 1 returns the image URL and a 0 returns the binary image data.

https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS/wiki/GetObject

Comment: Also, image URL won't be supporting by all RETS. So if you need URL for some reason, make sure public URL support is provided by the RETS.